# Why doesn't my .gif display on my browser?

Tags: html, css, gif

I am just trying to add an animated gif to a webpage and then animate it with CSS, but it does not seem to be displaying on the screen when testing it. I have tried it on Chrome, Safari and Firefox but had luck.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        body {

          background-color: #230190;

        }
          .wofly {
            background-image:url("img/sprite_002.gif");
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            position:absolute;
          }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class= "wolfy"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

It should just display in the `<div>` like the png's I had been using to animate with before.

Comment: can you show fiddle example ?

Comment: Could it be that your class is `.wofly` and the class you've assigned to the div is `wolfy`? You've typo'd one of them.

Comment: @IsmailFarooq the div should have a gif background but it appears the issue is a simple typo

Comment: omg, I am such a fool haha. Thanks @IsmailFarooq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you have problem with spelling

```css
.wolfy {
  background-image:url("https://codeproject.global.ssl.fastly.net/images/animated.gif");
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wolfy"></div>
```